# Wordpress always display the first menu

Tags: menus

I try to display multiple menus but Wordpress keep always display the first one I created...

Here is all the code about the menus:

**functions.php**

```
<?php function custom_init(){

  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header_quick_links' => __( 'Liens rapides du header' ),
      'header_menu'        => __( 'Menu du header' )
    )
  );

}

add_action('init', 'custom_init');
```

**header.php**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
  'menu'       => 'header_quick_links',
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'container'  => '',
  'menu_class' => 'header_quick_list'
)); ?>
...
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
  'menu'       => 'header_menu',
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'container'  => '',
  'menu_class' => 'header_menu_list'
)); ?>
```

And in the admin, each menu is correctly assign to the good location...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mismatching argument and input.

In rather confusingly worded way `register_nav_menus()` creates *menu locations* rather than actual *menus*. While `menu` argument in `wp_nav_menu()` expects menu as created in admin.

Since you seem to want to display menu, assigned to specific location, change `menu` in arguments to `theme_location`.